# facebook.stackoverflow.com links are not oneboxed in chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, mini-site, onebox

When pasting a URL (http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/###) into chat, I see the "working" indicator image for a second or two, but a onebox is not created.

Editing the post and removing `facebook.` from the URL makes it behave normally.

Comment: Here is an example: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1329311#1329311

Comment: Odd. Yes I see that issue here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1329311#1329311 This should be fixed.

Comment: Pasting a facebook.stackoverflow question URL into a question or answer also doesn't automatically turn that URL into a link with the title of the question as the link text like it does for all other SE sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works now. Since facebook.so is not a "real" site, it's not in the [StackAuth sites listing](http://stackauth.com/sites), that's why the links weren't recognized as "oneboxable". Until we have found a good way to expose mini-sites via the API, facebook.so is now hardcoded as being okay to onebox.

Note that even when you use a facebook.stackoverflow.com link, the link in the onebox will go to the canonical resource on stackoverflow.com.